# Split divs diagonally and responsively

Tags: javascript, css

I need to build the following screenshot, and I can't figure out how to do the angles responsively:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbdGZ.jpg

I tried using pseudo classes to add diagonal edges to a solid-color div.
But this design requires two images side-by-side so that won't work there. Also, the slants have to stay on the same angle through different sections with variable heights. I can't use clip-path because I need to support IE.

Here is my feeble attempt:
https://codepen.io/lsterling03/pen/zPEgaq

As you can see, I am having trouble! Is this design possible? Do you have any advice on how to approach this? Will it require javascript?

**UPDATE**

**I have made a little progress. Here is an updated pen:
https://codepen.io/lsterling03/pen/GOOqmo**

I can't get the slant right on the last section, which needs a variable height and width. I tried using javascript, but I don't have the right calculations:

```
        $(".slant").css('width', $('.main').width() * 0.5 - 100);
        $(".slant").css('border-top-width', $('.main').height());
```

I also haven't figured out how to do two images in a row yet.

Does anyone have suggestions to fix either of the above issues?

Comment: Do the images need to be changeable via a CMS? Is there an argument to make the images PNG with transparent pixels for the slants?

Comment: Unfortunately, yes, all images need to be editable via CMS. They may even need to use HTML5 background video in one of the slanted divs.

Comment: In my mind transparent PNGs would be the easiest for general CMS users to manage. Also, I'm not sure it will be possible to achieve the same degree angle on your slants when there are variable heights without JS. Finally, what would happen if the CMS user adds two side by side images with different heights..?

Comment: It's complicated, for sure. I would set a predefined image crop in wordpress to ensure images are all the same size. But they would need to police themselves to ensure they don't upload an image that is too small. These images would not be edited often.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something you can work with:

**Bootply**: https://www.bootply.com/4QuGRXY11d

```css
.container{position:relative;width: 500px; overflow:hidden;}
.flex{display:flex;overflow:hidden;}
.cinq{overflow:hidden;width:50%;height:150px;background:blue;}
.cinq + .cinq{oveflow:hidden;right:-25%;width:75%;height:150px;position:absolute;   transform: skewX(-20deg) translateX(-50px);background:red;}
.flex + .flex .cinq + .cinq{transform: skewX(20deg) translate(-50px)}
.cinq .img{height:100%;background-size:cover; background-image:url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/ca/9b/ca/ca9bca4db9afb09158b76641ea09ddb6.jpg);    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: -50px;transform: skewX(20deg);}

.flex + .flex .cinq + .cinq .img{transform: skewX(-20deg);}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="flex">
     <div class="cinq">1</div>
     <div class="cinq">
       <div class="img"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex">
     <div class="cinq">3</div>
     <div class="cinq"><div class="img"></div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to play around with this now. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

And, here is another example that you can start to investigate some more: [CodePen](https://codepen.io/ahdigital/pen/gXXOMP?editors=1100)

```
body {
  background-color: #00bcd4;
}

div { box-sizing:border-box; }

.row {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.image {
  background: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/ca/9b/ca/ca9bca4db9afb09158b76641ea09ddb6.jpg) center center no-repeat #eee;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%; 
  float: right;
}

.image2{
  background: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/ca/9b/ca/ca9bca4db9afb09158b76641ea09ddb6.jpg) center center no-repeat #eee;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 400px;
  width: 64.5%; 
  float: left;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 78% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 78% 100%, 0% 100%);
}

.image3{
  background: url(https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/564x/ca/9b/ca/ca9bca4db9afb09158b76641ea09ddb6.jpg) top left no-repeat #eee;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(28% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(28% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0% 100%);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.text {
  background-color: #eee;
  padding: 30px;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  height: 400px;
}

.text > div {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

.text2 {
  height: 400px;
  width: 50%; 
  float: left;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 30px
}

.corner:after {
  transition: all .3s ease;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
}

.corner-right:after {
  border-left: 150px solid #eee;
  border-top: 400px solid transparent;
  border-right: 270px solid transparent;
}

.corner-left:after {
  border-right: 150px solid #eee;
  border-top: 400px solid transparent;
  border-left: 270px solid transparent;
  right: 50%;
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! This already looks so much closer to what I need. I'm going to start digging in now, and will report back. Really appreciate your time!

Comment: Ah, I just noticed this is using clip-path, which won't work on IE. I wonder if I can use a clip-path polyfill....